# Delay javascript function and show only once

Tags: javascript, cookies, modal-dialog

This work on page load no problem :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
    $.UIkit.modal('#newsletter-20').show();
});
```

But I want to add a delay of 5 sec. I tried setTimeout("function()",5000) with no success.

Also in addition I would need to make this modal show only once. How do I do that?

Tks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need quotes for `setTimeout`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.UIkit.modal('#newsletter-20').show();
  }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see your code with `setTimeout`. But from your problem statement I guess you are putting setTimeout function inside quotes which is wrong.
Hope this snippet will be useful

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
 setTimeout(function(){
   $.UIkit.modal('#newsletter-20').show();
   }, 5000);

});
```